# How to check if AlwaysEncrypted is enabled on a Sitecore Collection Shards DB?

Tags: xconnect

We would like to know whether AlwaysEncrypted feature is ON/OFF for our Collection shards DB in Sitecore. We are working on the Upgrade to 10.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `<role-root>\App_data\config\Sitecore\Collection\sc.Xdb.Collection.Data.Sql.xml` configuration file and set the `UseAlwaysEncrypted` element to true

```
<UseAlwaysEncrypted>true</UseAlwaysEncrypted>
```

For more details refer this link.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/configure-sql-always-encrypted-for-the-xdb-collection-database.html

Comment: Thanks @Sumit Bhatia